# What is the difference between a .sl and a .so on HPUX?

Tags: unix, shared-libraries, hp-ux

Since you can link your application to a .sl file and a .so file what exactly are the differences between .so and .sl files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a quick googling, I found [this](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/System-Administration/so-and-sl-files/td-p/3780528).

```
*.so shared libraries are used in HP-UX 11.20 and upwards. 

*.sl are used in PA-RISC (11.11) 

Basically, *.so files reside in /usr/lib/hpux32 and /usr/lib/hpux64/ on Itanium. 

*.sl resides in /usr/lib
```